# how to create a global CGFloat accessed in a class without preprocessor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following in my .h class:

```
extern CGFloat tableMarginSide;
extern CGFloat tableMarginTop;
extern CGFloat fromImageSize;
extern CGFloat keyboardHeightPortrait;
extern CGFloat keyboardHeightLandscape;
```

and in my init I did:

```
 CGFloat tableMarginSide = 20;
    CGFloat tableMarginTop = 20;
    CGFloat fromImageSize = 50;

    CGFloat keyboardHeightPortrait  = 210;
    CGFloat keyboardHeightLandscape  = 160;

    if (IS_IPAD){
        CGFloat tableMarginSide = 80;
        CGFloat tableMarginTop = 65;
        CGFloat fromImageSize = 50;

        CGFloat keyboardHeightPortrait = 260;
        CGFloat keyboardHeightLandscape = 350;
    }
```

Why is it that I am getting warnings and I can't use this float in my class? Oh I don't want to use preprocessor by the way

Comment: Because `if` statements can't go in global scope. They must be within a function scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're re-decalring new variables with the same name in `init`. Inside of the `init` method, declaration are local to that block. What you mean is this:

### header

```
extern CGFloat tableMarginSide;
extern CGFloat tableMarginTop;
extern CGFloat fromImageSize;
extern CGFloat keyboardHeightPortrait;
extern CGFloat keyboardHeightLandscape;
```

### impl

```
CGFloat tableMarginSide = 20;
CGFloat tableMarginTop = 20;
CGFloat fromImageSize = 50;

CGFloat keyboardHeightPortrait  = 210;
CGFloat keyboardHeightLandscape  = 160;

@interface ...
- (id)init {
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
     if (IS_IPAD)
       tableMarginSide = 80;
       tableMarginTop = 65;
       fromImageSize = 50;

       keyboardHeightPortrait = 260;
       keyboardHeightLandscape = 350;
     }
   }
}
```

That said, this is exactly the kind of problem that nib files and storyboards are designed to deal with.

Even without nib files, I would avoid this approach. It is very dependent on making sure that you call `init` prior to accessing these globals (and it is very easy for this not to happen if you're not very careful). A better approach is to create class or instance methods for these rather than create "pseudo-constants" (which aren't really constant because they change at runtime).